# Python get all subclasses of Parent across multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I am *attempting* to avoid the messy iterations of entire directories to hunt down sub-classes of a parent class in python.

Right now I have a directory containing two files set up like so:

```
test (directory):
    - __init__.py
    - test1.py
```

In my `__init__.py` file is the following:

```py
class BaseMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct: dict):
        subclass = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        print(subclass)
        return subclass


class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
    pass


__all__ = [
    "Base"
]
```

and in my `test1.py` file I have:

```py
from test import Base


class Sub(Base):
    pass
```

I am running the `__init__` file, running the `test1` file *does* list out the sub-class `Sub`, but this fails when running the `__init__` file as python hasn't registered the `test1` file.

I am trying to make it such that inheriting `Base` on the `Sub` class prints out the `Sub` class (effectively "gets" the subclass) dynamically. Currently I am attempting this via a meta-class, but that has route has failed. I am aware of the `__subclasses__()` call introduced, but that only tracks *local* sub-classes, they *must* either be imported or exist in the same file as the parent class.

I have seen solutions in which one would iterate a directory looking for sub-classes of the Parent and dynamically importing them, but that is a sub-optimal solution.

Potential solutions outside of crawling a directory are preferred.

Any help would be *much* appreciated!

Comment: Trying to avoid what might be an X-Y problem, are you trying to load these other files dynamically, like plugins, without having to specify explicit imports of them? I'd put the files in e.g. a `plugins` folder, or use a naming convention like plugin_....py so they can be found in the filesystem, rather than grubbing around inside files searching for classes that inherit from Base.

Comment: Yep, attempting to load these like plugins, just attempting to avoid having to crawl a directory. If that's the only way to pull that off then I'll do it, but it seems very messy as an implementation.

Comment: How could Python know about any Subclasses in unloaded files? I don't see a way except importing/loading all potential modules/packages and then checking for Subclasses.

Comment: And that's what I was hoping wasn't the case. Hoped there was some magic there that could keep me from having to import. Everything I've seen and looked at thus far matches up with that.

I'll go ahead and close this out.